# How to convert ISO 8601 date format to specific format?

Tags: node.js

I am able to retrieve the dates and I want it to be converted to a format like `"1 week ago"` or `"2 week ago"`.

The date format I am inputting is in this format:`2016-02-15T19:43:14.412-0500`

Comment: Try this model [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/docs/) ?

Comment: I added moment.js.....Thanks it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [`fromNow()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) in [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/) to do it for you;

```
var moment = require('moment')

moment('2016-02-15T19:43:14.412-0500').fromNow();
// Outputs '20 days ago'
```

Comment: @Franklin If the answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as answering the question using the checkbox to the left of the answer. That will make life easier for others looking for a similar solution.